# How to "change the object key or version in the template" for AWS Lambda or S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have 14 AWS Lambdas that each reference the same code that's been compiled into a .jar file. Whenever I update the .jar, I don't want to update every single Lambda and upload the .jar again. For this reason, I decided to upload the .jar to a S3 bucket and then reference that code from the Lambdas.

This seems good, but I just [learned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47042416/4913592) that uploading new code to the .jar will not automatically update the Lambda. When referencing the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-lambda-function-code.html), it says the following:

> Changes to a deployment package in Amazon S3 are not detected
> automatically during stack updates. To update the function code,
> change the object key or version in the template.

What does it mean be changing the "object key or version in the template" and how is that done?

One thing I've tried is creating a [separate Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/new-deployment-options-for-aws-lambda/) to update all my other Lambdas which is triggered when my jar S3 bucket is changed, but this doesn't seem to be working either:

```
console.log('Loading function');
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var lambda = new AWS.Lambda();
exports.handler = function(event, context) {
    let key = event.Records[0].s3.object.key
    let bucket = event.Records[0].s3.bucket.name
    let version = event.Records[0].s3.object.versionId
    let functionNames = [
        "cs_340_tweeter_follow",
        "cs_340_tweeter_get_followers",
        "cs_340_tweeter_get_feed",
        "cs_340_tweeter_is_follower",
        "cs_340_tweeter_log_in",
        "cs_340_tweeter_register",
        "cs_340_tweeter_logout",
        "cs_340_tweeter_get_follower_count",
        "cs_340_tweeter_get_following",
        "cs_340_tweeter_get_following_count",
        "cs_340_tweeter_get_user",
        "cs_340_tweeter_unfollow",
        "cs_340_tweeter_post_status",
        "cs_340_tweeter_get_story"
        ]
        
    if (bucket == "cs340tweeterserverjar" && key == "server-all.jar" && version) {
        for (let i = 0; i < functionNames.length; i++) {
            var functionName = functionNames[i];
            console.log("uploaded to lambda function: " + functionName);
            var params = {
                FunctionName: functionName,
                S3Key: key,
                S3Bucket: bucket,
                S3ObjectVersion: version
            };
            lambda.updateFunctionCode(params, function(err, data) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err, err.stack);
                    context.fail(err);
                } else {
                    console.log(data);
                    context.succeed(data);
                }
            });
        }
    } else {
        context.succeed("skipping zip " + key + " in bucket " + bucket + " with version " + version);
    }
};
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Objects in S3 can be versioned. Where it's suggesting you specify a different object version, it's assuming:

- Your S3 bucket has versioning enabled.
- You've overwritten your JAR file, which should give you a new version ID.

From there, you can [use that version ID in your CloudFormation template where you're defining your Lambda functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-lambda-function-code.html).

Alternatively, you can upload the JAR under a different key for each version - `app-1.0.0.jar`, `app-1.0.1.jar` and so on. Then, again in your CloudFormation template, reference the new S3 path to trigger deployment.

If your issue is then getting that S3 path or version into your CloudFormation template without manually changing it for X Lambdas, [you can use a parameter](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html). You'll then be able to pass the value once and have it referenced across all of your Lambdas.

Comment: Thank you for the effort, I appreciate it! I ended up solving my problem with a bash script.